# Is it possible to decompose 3-factor change in growth rate terms?

Tags: methodology, mathematical-statistics, growth-model

Let's say, we investigate what caused the growth in working-age population (W). There are basically three factors causing the change in W. First, mortality at working ages (MT). Second, migration balance at working ages (MG). Finally, we have cohort turnover (CT) which is the number of those entering working ages minus the number of those leaving working ages (e.g. # of people turned 15 in some year minus # of people turned 65). So,

$$ W_2 - W_1 = MT + MG + CT $$

I want to know how much each factor contribute to the growth in W. The simple decomposition looks like

$$ \frac{W_2}{W_1} = \frac{W_1+MT+MG+CT}{W_1} = 1 + \frac{MT}{W_1} + \frac{MG}{W_1} + \frac{CT}{W_1}$$

Is there any way of decomposing growth in a form of product of three partial growth rates? Something like

$$ \frac{W_2}{W_1} = mt * mg * ct $$

Thanks in advance for any help, reference or hint.
This is my first question at CrossValidated. Excuse me if it is not worded properly.

Comment: Do I understand it well that $W=MG+MT+CT$ such that $\Delta W= \Delta MG + \Delta MT + \Delta CT$ and that you want a decomposition in relative growth of MT,MG,CT? Is a weighted sum of percentage growths also ok? E.g something like $w=a_1 mg +a_2 mt +a_3 ct$ where w, mg,mt, ct are percentage growths?

Comment: not precisely.  
$\Delta W$ is the difference in $W$ from $t_1$ to $t_2$.   
$MT$, $MG$, and $CT$ are the numbers of people _died_, _migrated_ or _entered/left (balance) working-ages_ during the period $t_1$ - $t_2$, respectively. So, $W$ refers to points in time, and the three change components refer to time interval.  Weighted sum of percentage growths is not what I want. I want to turn this additive decomposition into multiplicative form. I want each of the three  factor of change in $W$ to be a partial growth rate in the decomposition like $\frac{W_2}{W_1} = mt*mg*ct$